# How to access old entries of Vim Clipboard?

Tags: vim, clipboard, vi, clipboardmanager

When I want to copy a line and paste it in the current line after deleting the current line's contents, I end up pasting the same line that was deleted as the clipboard entry gets changed after pressing <kbd>d</kbd>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the previous content of the unnamed register with registers `"1` to `"9`:

```
"3p
```

Register `"0` always contains the last explicit yank:

```
"0p
```

And you can yank to a named register `"a` to `"z`. If you want to save a snippet for later, using named registers is a *very* good idea:

```
"ey
"ep
```

See `:help registers`.

Comment: So where does the second last yank gets stored? Seems it is not stored in 1 for me?

Comment: Woo, yanking to named registers is exactly what I was after but seldom mentioned in posts about yank registers. `"py` and `"pp` are my new favourite (n)vim commands :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the information given about registers already, you can type

```
:reg
```

to get a list of what is currently stored in all of the registers.

You can then use the 2-character code that is displayed on the left (beginning with a `"` eg. `"2`) followed by `p`while in normal mode to paste the contents of that register.

Comment: Is there a way to know the register contents without typing :reg, like most recent in 0, second most recent in 1, etc. Because I often need the second most recent value?

Comment: I'm unsure about yanks, but deleted content will be stored in successive registers.  So `"0` will always contain the last yank (unless another register was specified).  `"1` will contain the contents of the last delete or change command.  If you make another delete after this, the contents of register `"1` move to `"2`, and the recently deleted content moves to `"1`.

Answer (score 2):

To replace the current line with whatever is in the clipboard, you can select that line and paste. ie do a

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>